# React.useRef for ChakraUI Toast

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I can't work out what Type I need to provide for for React.useRef() given the following example code from the chakra docs:

```
function UpdatingToastExample() {
  const toast = useToast()
  const toastIdRef = React.useRef()

  function update() {
    if (toastIdRef.current) {
      toast.update(toastIdRef.current, { description: "new text" })
    }
  }

  function addToast() {
    toastIdRef.current = toast({ description: "some text" })
  }

  return (
    <Stack isInline spacing={2}>
      <Button onClick={addToast} type="button">
        Toast
      </Button>

      <Button onClick={update} type="button" variant="outline">
        Update last toast
      </Button>
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

From: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/feedback/toast#updating-toasts

Typescript obviously wants me to give a type for React.useRef() but I don't know what to give it?

```
 const toastIdRef = React.useRef<WhatTypeShouldThisBe?>(null);
```

I am using chakra-ui/react v1.6.7 and typescript 4.2.4.

Comment: What is the return value of that `toast` function, do you need to be more specific than that?

Comment: How about `any`?

Comment: any did work @hisam though I wanted to be more strict about it.

Comment: `any` also resolved the issues I found when trying trying to use the proper `ToastId` type in the answer from @DrewReese below.

However, I discovered that the Toast component is not easily stylable and I could handle my use-case easier by using a Slide and a Box component, and toggling it on and off with a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is either a string or a number:

```
const toastIdRef = React.useRef<number|string>(null);
```

Looks like you could import `ToastId` type:

[Toast props](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/feedback/toast#props)

[ToastId type](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/toast/src/toast.types.ts#L16)

> ```
> export type ToastId = string | number
> ```

```
import { useToast, ToastId } from "@chakra-ui/toast";

...

const toastIdRef = React.useRef<ToastId>(null);
```

[image: Edit react-useref-for-chakraui-toast]

Comment: Thanks! Importing the ToastID type was a great idea. That does satisfy the typing, but then I get an error complaining that toastIdRef.current is read only, when I try to assign something to it with `toastIdRef.current = toast({ description: "some text" })`.

Comment: I discovered that the toast is not stylable as well, so for now I have built a custom toast using Slide, and a Box component and toggling it on and off with a boolean, which fit my specific purpose better than the default toast did.